# Scaffolding Extension in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, scaffolding, vsix

I want to add scaffolding to my web form application. so I just installed the Web Forms Scaffolding Extension, but when I try to add the scaffold, it doesn't appear. (screenshot attached). also I uninstall & install again but nothing happen. Does anyone know what's the problem? [image: scaffold problem]